# Is it possible to use elif in a one-line if statement?

Tags: if-statement, one-liner

Example code:

```
print(one) if number == "1" elif print(two) if number == "2" else print("Please select 1 or 2")
```

at the elif it expected "else". Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That would depend on the language, which you forgot to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you should provide a language; however in python, it works like this:

```
print('one' if number == 1 else 'two' if number == 2 else 'Please select 1 or 2')
```

Answer (score -1):

In **python**:

```
number = 1

print('one' if number == 1 else 'two' if number == 2 else 'Please select 1 or 2')
```